# What's the meaning of the numbers at the end of the episode?

Tags: oregairu

At the end of any episode of *[Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Come wa Machigatteiru](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=14888)*, some numbers appears coupled with the title and the number of the next episode (circled).

[image: Ep. 4]

286

[image: Ep. 5]

266

[image: Ep. 9]

281

What's the meaning of these numbers?

Comment: I don't think there is any meaning to them (I checked the novels, but those are definitely not page number from the novel). They are most likely for the purpose of styling.

Comment: i get the feeling they are frame numbers or something related to the production of the show, if that makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Angel Beats!* also did something similar, except that the numbers, prefixed by the character 'c', appear in the previews for next episode.

[image: Angel Beats! next episode preview]

These are the **cut numbers** found in storyboards, or （絵）コンテ (*e konte*, from the English word *continuity*) in Japanese. According to [Anime Production – Detailed Guide to How Anime is Made and the Talent Behind it!](https://washiblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/anime-production-detailed-guide-to-how-anime-is-made-and-the-talent-behind-it/),

> Cuts refer to a single shot of the camera and an average TV-anime episode will usually contain around 300 cuts.

which basically matches the range of numbers that appear in both *Oregairu* and *Angel Beats!*.

To top it off, I was able to find a screenshot (click to enlarge) of a selection of *Oregairu*'s storyboards:

[image: Oregairu storyboard selection]

<sup>Image source: http://forum.gamer.com.tw/C.php?bsn=44991&snA=514</sup>

---

#### Corrections to OP's post

- The circled numbers actually mark the **current**, not the next, episode number. See the [list of titles for all episodes](http://www.anime.marumegane.com/2013/oregairu.html) (scroll down to the middle).
- The numbers/titles don't always appear at the end. For example, the title of episode 2

  > 17 ②きっと、誰しも等し並みに悩みを抱えている。

  appears very early, corresponding to the 17th scene (excluding the OP and ED) in that episode.

Comment: +1 Interesting finding, and it so far matches the appearance of the episode title for episode 2 and episode 7, though the title is not actually narrated.

Comment: I don't know the story of Oregairu, but the titles do seem like part of the conversations, though. They're like what the characters said/would have said in those situations.

Comment: The title for episode 10 appears right at the beginning. And also for episode 11. Not sure what you are talking about?

Comment: I don't think so. Visually speaking, it is extremely similar to the page and chapter indicator on top of every pages in the LN. However, the LN doesn't have chapters with the same titles (only similar titles). The LN's title format is <A connector word> <Character name> <Do something>, whereas there is no character names in the anime titles.